# linux c/c++: Get ifconfig wlan0 up output

Tags: c++, linux

I'm trying to run the command `ifconfig wlan0 up` and get the result of this command in the following way:

```
std::string exec(char* cmd)
{
 FILE* pipe = popen(cmd, "r");
 if (!pipe) return "ERROR";
 char buffer[128];
 std::string result = "";

 while(!feof(pipe)  ) 
 {
    if(fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != NULL)
        result += buffer;
 }
 pclose(pipe);
 return result;

}
```

However, when calling the above function with `ifconfig wlan0 up`, it returns empty result (though the command is successful).

Expected result (when running from command prompt):

```
[   68.126342] wl12xx: state: 0
[   68.683715] wl12xx: firmware booted (Rev 6.3.10.0.135)
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Isn't that the desired result? AFAIK it doesn't chatter when it works.

Comment: Is that result written to the standard output by ifconfig?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ifconfig up` doesn't produce output when successful.

The messages you see in the console (*wl12xx: firmware booted*) are log messages from the *kernel*, and it looks like your system is configured to copy the log to the console. You'll likely find the same messages in a file under `/var/log`.

You can confirm that the messages do not come from ifconfig by redirecting the output to a file, for example

```
ifconfig wlan0 up 2>&1 >/tmp/output
```

Answer (score 0):

The popen() function creates a pipe between the calling program  and  the  command  to  be  executed. Don't see any problem in your program snippet. Check whether the command you execute is really producing any output to show. Also check if your buffer is adequately sized.